# Является ли слово "семья" одушевленным?

Tags: морфология

По идее, семья состоит из людей или животных, значит, это понятие должно быть одушевленным. Однако же изменяется это слово как неодушевленное: в винительном падеже будет "семьи", а не "семей". "Поставил ульи, чтобы заселить туда семьи (пчел)".
Почему слово "семья" не является одушевленным?

Answer (score 3):

Одушевленность - категория не биологическая, а грамматическая, так что "живой - не живой" здесь не катит. Сравните пресловутых мертвеца, покойника (одушевленные) и труп (неодушевленное).

Answer (score 1):

То же самое можно отнести к микробам. Которые изменяются то как одушевленные, то как неодушевленные. Искать причин сейчас уже не стоит. Категория одушевленность -неодушевленность сложилась исторически.

Answer (score 1):

Существительное "семья" имеет собирательное значение, почему оно должно быть одушевленным?

К примеру, рота солдат тоже состоит из людей, но рота - это неодушевленное существительное.